# Will empty variables impact my code? (PHP)

Tags: php, arguments

In other words, say I have

```
$existingVariable = 'This is set';
echo thisFunction($existingVariable, $nonExistingVariable);

//included file
function thisFunction($existingVariable){
  echo $existingVariable;
}
```

$nonExistingVariable is no longer there because the included file has changed.

So the way I understand it, `$nonExistingVariable` would = `''` or `NULL`, right? Does this have any real impact on my code? I'll remove them (or add them back to the included file) before release, but I was just curious if having non-existing variables as an argument risked functionality issues.

Comment: Easy way to know is set error reporting to E_ALL and test it out and you will have your answer. O_o

Comment: They do indeed throw errors, but what I'm getting at is does `Undefined variable` actually slow down my code or have the potential to cause actual functionality problems.  Benno answered my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not affect the function of your code, unless you are using `func_get_args();` to work with your arguments instead of just specifying them (you are specifying them, so it won't have any affect)

I.E. you could be doing:

```
function test() {

$args = func_get_args();

$b = $args[0];
$c = $args[1];
echo "$b\n$c";
}
test('dog','cat');
outputs: 
dog
cat
```

It will affect the readability and user-friendliness of your code moving forward though, as you may try and copy and paste a function call from an old area of code, and get stuck trying to figure out why the variable isn't getting passed into the function (because its no longer an argument).

Why not just remove it, if its not being used anymore?

Comment: The variables do exist, they are `$dbFieldname` that represents the scripting needed to actually get the row item from the database. It's just for a little while, just wondered what happens to them.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable doesn't exist then yes PHP will give you an error. "Undefined Variable". You can assign a NULL value, $nonExistingVariable= NULL; Or you can do

if (!empty($nonExistingVariable))

To prevent errors